# Is there a way to redirect the user request in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to build a dialogflow agent that translates a different language to English and translates the output from the agent back into English. However, after detecting the user's language and translating the user request, is there a way I can send it in for dialogflow to detect the intent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to use webhook for this as Dialogflow sends you the query before processing it, then you can create another session and send the translated message to dialoflow, returning the intent and the response, which you can then put into your initial webhook response.