# Realtime live agent text translation CCAI and dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx, contact-center

Hi is there a way to get the realtime chat of agent and user from CCAI to dialogflow after the bot trasfer the conversation to agent.

Need the agent message and then translate it to another language and send it to the user. How to implement this.

Comment: Hi @sariga ms, Can you check this [Documentation1](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-builder-1#4) and [Documentation2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-multilingual#:~:text=Dialogflow%20supports%20many%20languages.,you%20can%20add%20additional%20languages.) and this [stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118757/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-the-user-request-in-dialogflow). I hope it will help you.